# Stop word wrapping of Write-Warning and Write-Debug on powershell.exe

Tags: powershell, word-wrap

### Background

- On `powershell.exe`, when you write messages with `Write-Warning` or `Write-Debug`, Japanese strings without spaces are wrapped automatically.

  - On PowerShell ISE, these cmdlets don't wrap messages.
- `Write-Error` wraps messages in both environments.
- `Write-Host`, `Write-Output`, and `Write-Information` don't wrap messages in both environments.

### Example

```
$message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. いろはにほへとちりぬるをわかよたれそつねならむうゐのおくやまけふこえてあさきゆめみしゑひもせす."
Write-Host ("Write-Host Message: {0}" -F $message)
Write-Output ("Write-Output Message: {0}" -F $message)
Write-Error ("Write-Error Message: {0}" -F $message) -ErrorAction Continue
Write-Information ("Write-Information Message: {0}" -F $message) -InformationAction Continue
Write-Warning ("Write-Warning Message: {0}" -F $message) -WarningAction Continue
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
Write-Debug ("Write-Debug Message: {0}" -F $message)
```

On `powershell.exe`:
[image: Result on powershell.exe]

On PowerShell ISE:

[image: Result on PowerShell ISE]

### Question

I want to show Japanese messages of `Write-Error`, `Write-Warning`, or `Write-Debug` without word wrapping on `powershell.exe`.

Is there any way to stop word wrapping of these cmdlets like `overflow-wrap: break-word;` in CSS?

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by telling Powershell the size of the window, rather than letting it detect it. Simply add these three lines before the rest of your code, and you'll find when your existing lines of code are run, all the text appears on a single line.

```
$max = $host.UI.RawUI.MaxPhysicalWindowSize
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(9999,9999)
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size($max.Width,$max.Height)

$message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. いろはにほへとちりぬるをわかよたれそつねならむうゐのおくやまけふこえてあさきゆめみしゑひもせす."
Write-Host ("Write-Host Message: {0}" -F $message)
Write-Output ("Write-Output Message: {0}" -F $message)
Write-Error ("Write-Error Message: {0}" -F $message) -ErrorAction Continue
Write-Information ("Write-Information Message: {0}" -F $message) -InformationAction Continue
Write-Warning ("Write-Warning Message: {0}" -F $message) -WarningAction Continue
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
Write-Debug ("Write-Debug Message: {0}" -F $message)
```

Note, the one weird effect I've seen with this in testing is that from the ISE it just runs normally, but in powershell.exe if you have the window smaller than the screen size, it will increase the size to fit your screen. Shrinking the window down again will re-introduce wrapping. But, if you're running it on a small screen (so the powershell.exe is already full screen and wrapping) it will do what you're looking for and put all the text on one line with a scroll bar at the bottom.

Comment: On PowerShell ISE, `$host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize` causes an error, but the other cmdlet works as desired. On `powershell.exe` with the command prompt, `$host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize` enlarges the window size, and slows down performance of terminal. This behavior is a bit annoying. But on `powershell.exe` with Windows Terminal, this works perfectly (doesn't change the window size). Thanks!

Comment: @SATOYusuke, you can just omit the `$host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize = ...` line, which is of questionable value even in regular (`conhost.exe`) console windows, given that it doesn't also
place the maximized window in the top-left corner (doing so programmatically would be nontrivial), so you'll have to move it manually - just double-clicking the title bar is simpler.

Comment: @SATOYusuke, by setting the buffer width to the max., this solution introduces a _horizontal scrollbar_ for line in regular console windows and in the ISE.
In Windows Terminal, it doesn't show a scrollbar and still performs line-wrapping based on the window width, but the word-wrapping problem goes away, because the _buffer_ width is
reported as the window width to applications. However, this can cause problems, such as with the list-style prediction view of `PSReadLine`.

Answer (score 1):

Preface:

- **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now *does* exhibit the desired behavior**, so no workaround is required there.
- The **workaround for *Windows PowerShell*** below **addresses the problem of *word*-wrapping, not *line*-wrapping** as such.

  - That is, in the context of line-wrapping due to *limited window width*, it **tries to address the problem that the [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) string is inappropriately considered a *word*, as a result of which it is wrongly assumed that it  *shouldn't be broken apart***, causing it to be placed on the *next* line.
  - Both the window and the buffer size are left untouched, which means that *line*-wrapping may still occur (but not *word*-wrapping).
- By contrast, **[Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77204390/45375) *bypasses* the problem** altogether, by avoiding *line-wrapping itself*, by increasing the console-window *buffer size* as well as the *window size* to its maximum, which implies:

  - With lines that are wider than the window, you **may therefore have to perform *horizontal scrolling***.
  - Conversely, if the window is wide enough, you may not have to increase the buffer size.

---

In *Windows PowerShell*, the `Write-*` cmdlets in question apparently perform *word*-wrapping, even though it isn't appropriate for CJK strings (that is - from what I understand - there's no good reason *not* to break a CJK string arbitrarily at the end of a line during *line*-wrapping - it needn't be considered a *word* that shouldn't be broken apart).

The following ***suboptimal* workaround** *may* help:

- It merges the output from all `Write-*` cmdlets into the *success* [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) via [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `*>&1`...
- ... detects objects that came from *other* streams and prints their message / string representation via `Write-Host`, emulating the original output format, in a manner that does *not* involve word-wrapping.

Note: Due to use of `Write-Host` for all non-success-stream output, the net effect of this workaround is that all such output is routed *to the information stream*.

```bash
# Sample write commands.
$writeCommands = {
  $message = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. いろはにほへとちりぬるをわかよたれそつねならむうゐのおくやまけふこえてあさきゆめみしゑひもせす.'
  Write-Host ('Write-Host Message: {0}' -F $message)
  Write-Output ('Write-Output Message: {0}' -F $message)
  Write-Error ('Write-Error Message: {0}' -F $message) -ErrorAction Continue
  Write-Verbose ('Write-Verbose Message: {0}' -F $message) -Verbose
  Write-Information ('Write-Information Message: {0}' -F $message) -InformationAction Continue
  Write-Warning ('Write-Warning Message: {0}' -F $message) -WarningAction Continue
  $DebugPreference = 'Continue'
  Write-Debug ('Write-Debug Message: {0}' -F $message)
} 

# Map stream types to their display color
$colorMap = @{ Error = 'Red'; Verbose = 'Yellow'; Debug = 'Yellow'; Warning = 'Yellow' }

# Map stream types to their usual display prefixes
# LOCALIZE IF NEEDED.
$prefixMap = @{ Warning = 'WARNING: ';  Verbose = 'VERBOSE: '; Debug = 'DEBUG: '  }

& $writeCommands *>&1 | 
  ForEach-Object {  
    if ($_.GetType().FullName -match '^System\.Management\.Automation\.(\w+)Record$') {
      # Non-success-stream output.
      $streamType = $Matches[1]
      $prefix = $prefixMap.$streamType
      $colorArg = if ($color = $colorMap[$streamType]) { @{ ForegroundColor = $color } } else { @{} }
      # $_ | format-list force | out-host
      $msg = if ($streamType -eq 'Error') {
          # Emulate the standard error display formatting.
          @"
$($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName): $_
$($_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)
    + CategoryInfo          : $($_.CategoryInfo)
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : $($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId)
"@
        } else {
          "${prefix}${_}"
        }
      Write-Host @colorArg $msg
    }
    else {
      # success-stream output, pass through
      $_
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This workaround also works and doesn't cause window resize or performance penalty. But this suppresses the CategoryInfo and FullyQualifiedErrorId in error messages. This also changes the head of messages to English in the Japanese environment (`警告`->`WARNING`).

Comment: @SATOYusuke, please see my update, which now emulates the for-display output for errors too.
Also, I've added a `$prefixMap` hashtable where you can localize the stream-type prefixes such as `WARNING: `.
Note that your screenshots show the English prefixes, however, and, on my US-English machine, if I switch
temporarily to the Japanese culture, they remain in English too (as do the labels in the error message, such as `CategoryInfo`).